# What does muwaah mean?

Tags: meaning, sounds, onomatopoeia

I am not a native English speaker. Anyways, there's this girl in my class who quite frequently bunks and she relies on me for notes. I am basically her asset who does all her assignments and other stuffs like doing completing her algorithm and Program assignments/projects. I don't mind, but, I have noticed that she always uses the word muwaah or something like that at the end of our conversations/messages. What does that even mean? I tried asking her once but she just laughed so hard and told muwaah and went away.In my years of learning English I have never come across of this word. Sorry, my native is not English language so I don't have that great vocabulary. Also, How do you even pronounce that word !?!?

Comment: It's onomatopoeia for a kissing noise. The big sloppy kind your aunt gives you on the cheek.

Comment: I'll add that a closer approximation to the typical pronunciation would likely be "mmmwah", a bit like the French "moi", though with the `m` sound stretched out a bit.  (But the pronunciation of such terms will vary widely.)

Comment: Clearly here it's the kissing noise, but it can also be the first "word" of the cackle an evil villain makes as he commences his plan: "*muwaah ha ha*"

Comment: This word is used in 'Urdu' language conversations. My language is Urdu and we see this word normally in conversations of lovers or people in a relationship. It refers to kissing.

Comment: Off-topic, but rather important: The girl is taking advantage of you. She's abusing your kindness, and judging by your username, your low self-esteem. I strongly suggest you reconsider whether it's good for you to keep doing her homework just to have her laugh at your face.

Comment: Honestly, I'm getting the feeling that you already knew what it means and made this post as a joke :P

Comment: It's a typical non-english-origin word. I can say this because even people having no knowledge of English use this word frequently. Just the other day my sister called me and said "Muahh, I love you brother, missing u so much." I am a native Nepali and we use this word often. I noticed that not only in Nepali but this word is also used often in Hindi, Urdu, English and many other languages. It's almost like a universal word that is used to express "kissing".

Comment: This is a very awkward question. Sounds like poor boundaries or a mis-characterization. In any case it's good advice to ensure you're not being taken advantage of. Keep in mind that people who shirk sometimes are just overwhelmed and not sure how to ask for help. Learning is not about schoolwork: it's about the process.

Comment: Not to be confused with mwahaha, which is how villains laugh in Final Fantasy games.

Answer (score 16):

It is onomatopoeia for the sound of kissing.

A sign of affection which can sometimes be considered flirting.

[Oxford dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mwah):

> Used to represent the sound of a kiss, typically one given in an
>   exaggerated or theatrical way:
>
> 'Mwah, mwah! How are you, dahling?'

As Hot Licks mentions in the comments, it is pronounced similarly to the French pronoun "moi" (i.e. "mwah").

Comment: Just noticed dan bron covered this in the comments, apologies!

Comment: No problem, +1 from me. If you can find some kind of source to add weight to your answer, so much the better.

Comment: yeah cheers baller!

Answer (score 7):

For a clear and convincing representation of how "mwah!" was pronounced by 17-year-old girls in Queens, New York, in 1964, you can't do better than to consult "[Give Him a Great Big Kiss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-NhojnwMh8)" by the [Shangri-Las](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shangri-Las). The relevant lyrics leading up to the critical moment are:

> Gonna walk right up to him/Give him a great big kiss—mwaah!

You can hear the "mwaah!" twice during this recording of the song—at 0:40 and again at 1:34. "Give Him a Great Big Kiss" is also a great place to hear how 17-year-old girls in Queens, New York, in 1964 pronounced the word *dancer* (at 1:42 and 1:45). "Whudduyuh mean, 'Is he a good dancer?'"